# Does jqGrid have a row swap feature?

Tags: jqgrid

I wonder if jqGrid has a built in "row swapping" feature.

It is sometime that I have looked for it on the internet, but no luck so far.

But similar features are (and none can be used for row swaps without problems); DnD and sortableRows;

sortableRows will only change the order of the rows and no way to implement swapping intuitively for users.

In DnD, to make it work best, you need to assign the target to another HTML element or to another jqGrid. But, If you set it to the same jqGrid (to simulate row swapping), it will not allow it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically one uses grids sorted by some column. In the case reordering or swapping of rows have no sense. If you have unsorted grid and need to swap rows you can try to use [jQuery.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method to remove rows temporary from the grid and then use [jQuery.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [jQuery.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [jQuery.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) or [jQuery.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) to insert detached rows in the new location.

**UPDATED**: [The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UsageDetachInjqGrid.htm) demonstrate the usage of [jQuery.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) in the grid. It has rows with ids "10", "20", "30", "40", ...

I included two buttons on the demo (with id="move" and id="swap"). The first button do simple unconditional work: it detaches the row with id="10" and place it before the row with id="40".

The second button swap rows with ids "10" and "20" using `insertAfter` or `insertBefore` methods. Because of different positions of both rows in the grid one from the method can't be used. Additionally if the rows with ids "10" and "20" are one over another one one need to make only one move of rows. I tried to take in consideration all the cases. The corresponding code you will see below. I suppose that one can write more optimized code, but the code which I include below seems still work correctly:

```js
$("#move").button().click(function () {
    var $row = $("#10").detach();
    $row.insertBefore("#40");

    $(this).button("disable");
});
$("#swap").button().click(function () {
    var $row1 = $("#10"), $row2 = $("#20"),
        $next1 = $row1.next(".jqgrow"), $prev1 = $row1.prev(".jqgrow"),
        $next2, $prev2, doOneMove = false, movedOnce = false;

    if ($row2.is($next1) || $prev1.is($row2)) {
        doOneMove = true;
    }

    if ($prev1.length > 0 && !$prev1.is($row2)) {
        $row2.detach().insertAfter($prev1);
        movedOnce = true;
    } else if ($next1.length > 0 && !$next1.is($row2)) {
        $row2.detach().insertBefore($next1);
        movedOnce = true;
    }

    if (doOneMove && movedOnce) {
        return;
    }

    $next2 = $row2.next();
    $prev2 = $row2.prev();
    if ($prev2.length > 0 && !$prev2.is($row1)) {
        $row1.detach().insertAfter($prev2);
    } else if ($next2.length > 0 && !$next2.is($row1)) {
        $row1.detach().insertBefore($next2);
    }
});
```

Comment: That is OK, but what I really want is to be able to use jqGrid's drag and drop functionality with in the same grid. And copying the dragged row's content without removing the original row from the grid. Basically DnD on the same grid and to be able to drag i.e first row to the last row. Currently I cannot do that. Dragging first row to the rows other than the last row is supported and I can do that. The only problem is the dragging to the last row

Comment: @myuce: gridDnD just uses `addRowData` and `delRowData` internally. `sortableRows` uses jQuery UI internally which uses `.detach` which I suggested you. I created the demo which demonstrates my suggestion. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: I added an item to the grid menu and implemented as you have suggested.  But it would have been nice with the visual of gridDnD and the mouse dragging/dropping the rows. Thank you.

Comment: This code has a bug in it.  The line `if (!$next1.is($row2))` should be changed to `if (next1.length > 0 && !$next1.is($row2))`. Otherwise when you try to swap #40 and #30, it will clobber #30.

Comment: @JohnHenckel: Thanks! I think you are write, but one need to change *two* lines: `} else if (!$next1.is($row2)) {` to `} else if (next1.length > 0 && !$next1.is($row2)) {` and `} else if (!$next2.is($row1)) {` to `} else if (next2.length > 0 && !$next2.is($row1)) {`. I wanted just shows the main idea of the implementation in my code. I can imagine that there are more special cases, which should be tested. I updated the code of the answer now.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for your help. here is a demo with the corrections. http://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/oLvc1ejh/4/

Comment: @Oleg, as you can see I have separated the DOM manipulation into a function swapTwoTableRows.  it return true on success. I am pretty sure that, if the keys are valid, it will never return false... but I cannot prove it!!!

Comment: @JohnHenckel: Sorry, but I'm not sure what is your question and how I can help you. I fixed the code and the demo which I published. You can use the code as an example and rewrite corresponds to your purposes. I don't recommend you to use and **global** functions (`swapTwoTableRows` and `moveCurrentRowJQGrid` will be defined outside of and outer functions) and you should change the "LOAD TYPE" property of JavaScript window from "onLoad" to "no wrap - in <head>" for example if you want to use `$(document).ready(function() {...});` inside.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/netroworx/6wMm7/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#mytable").jqGrid({
  datatype:"clientSide",
  data:[ {"number": 1, "segment":"first", "name": "chap0"},
         {"number": 2, "segment":"second",  "name": "chap1"},
         {"number": 3, "segment":"third",  "name": "chap2"},
       ],
  colNames:['Chapter Name', 'Chapter Number', 'Document Segment'],
  colModel:[
          {name:'name'},
          {name:'number', sorttype:'number'},
          {name:'segment'},
          ],
  autowidth:true,
  height:'200',
  sortname: 'number',
  viewrecords: true,
  caption: 'My first grid',
  altRows:true

}); 
jQuery("#mytable").sortableRows();   
jQuery("#mytable").jqGrid('gridDnD');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about swapping adjacent rows, the following code will work.  Basically it will MOVE the current ROW either UP or DOWN.

```
function moveCurrentRowJQGrid(grid, moveUP) {
    var key = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if (!key) return;
    var row = $('#'+ key);
    if (moveUP) {
        var prev = row.prev('.jqgrow');
        if (prev.length > 0) {
            row.detach().insertBefore(prev);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        var next = row.next('.jqgrow');
        if (next.length > 0) {
            row.detach().insertAfter(next);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

It will return 1 if success, or undefined on failure (eg you tried to move the first row up).